# What's different with notification set channel and FCM subscribeToTopic?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

My app have a member system(member type include A、B、C), i use Firebase `FCM` to push notification to my app.

If the user login with A, i will use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("A");` and `unsubscribeFromTopic("B");` `unsubscribeFromTopic("C");`

It works very well until i find that if device's API >=26 my app notification will not show out. The reason is set channel is a importance update for latest android version.

I have change my notification code , just like this:

```
// For API >=26
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
            "A",
            "A",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel.setDescription("description");
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.enableVibration(true);

    Notification.Builder builder =
            new Notification.Builder(mContext)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setChannelId("A");
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Now i can show out notification if `FCM` push from A.

Obviously if i want to get from B or C then i should set channel B or C.

But member type A should only can get from A , so i find the official doc talk aout `Delete a notification channel`:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// The id of the channel.
String id = "my_channel_01";
mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(id);
```

I'm confused with that so what the meaning of my `FCM` `subscribeToTopic("A");` and `unsubscribeFromTopic("B");` `unsubscribeFromTopic("C");`

Should i write another code `setChannel(id);` and `deleteNotificationChannel(id);` only for API >=26 ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try by keeping Channel ID constant & just playing with Topics subscribe/unsubscribe?.

Comment: AFAIU Topic is related to interest whereas Channel is just a medium to get specific Type/Category of notifications irrespective of interest. Please correct me if wrong

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your `Channel ID` means `FCM` register id, right ?

Comment: No. It is just an INT val e.g. 1, 2 or ..

Comment: No i didn't try it before.  You mean `setChannelId("A");` ?  But it should be String argument, i still try it `setChannelId("1");' When send notification from `FCM` , my app log will show `No channel found`.

Comment: Did you place same channel name @FCM messaging dashboard?

Comment: No, i set channel in `FCM` just like A、B、C

Comment: Make sure Channel Name must be selected @FCM same as Channel name is given in code

Comment: I reinstall my app and run another test if i don't use `createNotificationChannel("A");`  then i send message from `FCM` , my notification will not show out. So i use `createNotificationChannel("A");` the notification will show out. So i think there must be a relationship between them.

Comment: createNotificationChannel is mandatory step to create channel else you will never get notifications. I mean you will get but can't be seen there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This both things are different,

**Topic Subscribe:**
Topic subscription is related to FCM or we can say Firebase Messaging when anyone sends notification using topic at that time they decide where we need to submit the message or in which device needs to send.

**Chanel Subscription:** 
This is related to particular notification system or device not related to any type of server or cloud message. When you defining the channel that means you are defining notification group at the display time.
If you defining topic as news then you get the only notification which broadcast only for news topic but you can divide news in the different group using notification channel or news subcategory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean set channel to the notification is just a classification right ? But i still don't get the point. Why my notification `.setChannelId("B");` than send message from Firebase (which channel is A), my notification will not show out ? I have to `.setChannelId("A");`

Answer (score 7):

**Topic**  is a string identifier for a group message. When a notification is sent about a topic, all devices that registered to that topic would get it.

A developer of a news app, might use this mechanism to allow users to select topics of interest to get alerts about, like:  Weather, Cars, Finance, Crime etc

While some apps define multiple topics that the user himself can subscribe and unsubscribe, some apps use this mechanism to send notification to all users, by defining a topic, and register all user (hard coded) to this topic.

**Channel**  is a set of settings defining how user would get alerted when notification arrive to the device.

Usually the developer would define the sound, vibration, light and more settings for each channel. User can always change those settings and even disable notification from specific channel.

A developer of a news app, might define a channel with vibration and high sound for breaking news, while creating a silent channel with low priority for promotions